# Pure React Native app crashes on swiping after opening it in Release mode

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using **React-Navigation** for my pure **RN 0.61.2** app. The app runs perfectly when I use it on Debug mode. However, in Release mode when I try to open the **Drawer Navigation** menu or scroll down in a **Tab** menu, the app crashes immediately.

Dependencies:

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^4.4.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^2.0.2",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.2",
    "react-native-admob": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-screens": "1.0.0-alpha.23",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.2.2",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.9.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.5"
  },
...
```

I've already added these lines of code to `android/app/build.gradle`'s dependencies:

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02'
```

In App.js, I tried

```
import {enableScreens} from 'react-native-screen';
enableScreens();
```

and also

```
import {useScreens} from 'react-native-screen';
useScreens();
```

with `2.0.0-alpha.1`, `2.0.0-alpha.3` and `1.0.0-alpha.23` versions of `react-native-screens`.

Yet, still I am getting the same result: Debug mode is perfectly working, Release mode is dramatically crashing after a Drawer Navigation swipe or a Tab Navigation scroll.

---

**THE SOLUTION**
I used `adb logcat` and saw this:

```
ReactNativeJS: Invariant Violation: Unsupported top level event type "onGestureHandlerStateChange" dispatched
```

I googled it and found that some guys have fixed it by importing 'react-native-gesture-handler' on the top of the 'app.js' file. So I've added:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'
```

and it is working perfectly now!

Comment: Use Android Studio Logcat to get the crash stacktrace, this should point you in the good direction...

Comment: @Vinzzz Logcat output was so helpful. Thank you very much! I've added the logcat output and the solution above.

Comment: Glad you could help yourself ;)

Comment: Glad you could help yourself, the solution is provided in the official documentation. 
It says:

"To finalize the installation of react-native-gesture-handler, add the following at the top (make sure it's at the top and there's nothing else before it) of your entry file, such as index.js or App.js:

import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

Note: If you skip this step, your app may crash in production even if it works fine in development."

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html